# Update data on Qt QDataWidgetMapper while mapper index stay unchanged

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to map data from a [QAbstractTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html) to a custom view using [QDataWidgetMapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html). The mapper is working correctly but the data mapped are not updated automatically according to changes in the model. I need to change manually the **currentMapperIndex** to trigger changes on my custom view.

I tried to simplify at maximum my problem.

**TableModel :**

```
class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.columns = ['Col1', 'Col2']
        self.datatable = []

    def update(self, dataIn):
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self.datatable = dataIn
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.datatable)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.columns)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.columns[section].title()

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
            row = self.datatable[index.row()]
            column_key = self.columns[index.column()]
            return row[column_key]
        else:
            return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if not index.isValid() or role != Qt.EditRole:
            return False
        if self.datatable:
            column_key = self.columns[index.column()]

            self.datatable[index.row()][column_key] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [])
            return True
        return True
```

---

**Custom View :**

```
class CustomView(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomView, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupLayout()
        self.spinboxMapperIndex.valueChanged.connect(self.changeMapperIndex)

    def setModel(self, model):
        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper()
        self.mapper.setModel(model)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.lineEdit1, 0)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.lineEdit2, 1)
        self.mapper.toFirst()

    def changeMapperIndex(self, index):
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(index)

    def setupLayout(self):

        self.spinboxMapperIndex = QSpinBox()

        self.lineEdit1 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit2 = QLineEdit()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.spinboxMapperIndex)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit1)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit2)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

---

**Main :**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = TableModel()

    table = QTableView()
    table.setModel(model)
    table.show()

    data = [ {'Col1': 11, 'Col2': 12},
             {'Col1': 21, 'Col2': 22},
             {'Col1': 31, 'Col2': 32}]
    model.update(data)

    view = CustomView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.show()

    newData = [ {'Col1': 111, 'Col2': 112},
                {'Col1': 121, 'Col2': 122},
                {'Col1': 131, 'Col2': 132}]
    model.update(newData)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

By running the code above, one can see that the TableView is well updated with the new data while the CustomView mapped data are not updated unless I change manually the spinbox for changing the mapper index.

On the [QDataWidgetMapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html) documentation we can read:

> Note that QDataWidgetMapper keeps track of external modifications. If the contents of the model are updated in another module of the application, the widgets are updated as well.

which doesn't seem to be the case ...

Any help would be appreciated, even written in Qt C++ form.

**EDIT :**

Changes on `update` method according to `Kuba Ober` answer :

```
def update(self, dataIn):
    self.beginResetModel()
    self.datatable = dataIn
    self.endResetModel()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model doesn’t fulfill the contract that every Qt model has to fulfill. Part of the problem is with the model, not with the mapper. Namely, `update` should use the `beginResetModel` and `endResetModel` methods. You’re not supposed to be emitting the layout change signals yourself. In fact, the only predefined signal you should emit yourself from a model is `dataChanged` - other signals are emitted by `QAbstractItemModel` in reaction to calls to `beginAction` and `endAction`.

After the model has been reset, the view should reset the current index - after all, during a reset, the model has, effectively, no rows - and the current index becomes invalid. Thus, add the following to `CustomView.setModel`:

```
self.model.modelReset.connect(self.mapper.toFirst)
```

Arguably, perhaps the mapper should set up such connection by itself, but it doesn't - thus you have to do that.